# Single WCF service for all inheriting class types

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, webservice-client

I've got a base class structure as follows.

```
class Mammal { ... }
class Human : Mammal { ... }
class Tiger : Mammal { ... }
class Snake : Mammal { ... }
```

Since the service is performing actions based on the properties in the *Mammal* class only, I see no need to create a separate web method for each type (and one could also use a conditional statement otherwise).

The error I'm getting is that I need to declare a translator or something like that and given that I recall a discussion about it (can't find it now, though), I wonder if that's doable at all. I remember somebody telling me that the inheritance structure is not possible to recreate when working with WCF.

Is there a way to solve that or should I simply keep a number of exposed services that do the same call but receive the input of the different types each?

**EDIT**

To clarify what I'm looking for, I'd like to runt the following code.

```
Human human = new Human { ... };
Tiger tiger = new Tiger { ... };
Snake snake = new Snake { ... };

ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
client.DoStuffTo(human);
client.DoStuffTo(tiger);
client.DoStuffTo(snake);
client.Close();
```

The signature for the service is as follows.

```
[OperationContract(Name = "DoStuffTo")]
[WebInvoke]
String DoStuffTo(Mammal mammal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute`

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx

and at this article

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx

Comment: I'll do that right now. Just to be clear, I edited my question a bit to exemplify what I'm optimally aiming at.